# Sorting table in react. How it's possible when only one column works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, columnsorting

I'd like to sort table items (alphabetical) by clicking on table header. I've tried to do it myself, but it works really strange, only clicking on second header (priority) works... And when I click on first and third header, it sorts table items in order how they were put in there.

I use `orderBy` from `lodash`.

Here is my code, the slice of the full class.

```
const header = [
    {name: "Task Name", id: "taskName"},
    {name: "Priority", id: "priority"},
    {name: "Done", id: "done"},
];

        <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
        {header.map((el, i) => (
            <TableCell key={i}>
                <div
                    style={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        alignItems: 'center'
                    }}
                    onClick={() => this.props.handleSort(el.id)}
                >

                    {el.name}
                    {
                        this.props.columnToSort === el.id
                            ? (this.props.sortDirection === 'asc'
                                ? <UpArrow/>
                                : <DownArrow/>
                            )
                            : null
                    }
                </div>
            </TableCell>
        ))}
        <TableCell/>
        </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
```

And logics in different class, "connected" by props.

```
const invertDirection = {
   asc: "desc",
   desc: "asc",
};

class...

state = {
    columnToSort: '',
    sortDirection: 'desc',
};

handleSort = (columnName) => {
    this.setState({
        columnToSort: columnName,
        sortDirection:
            this.state.columnToSort === columnName
                ? invertDirection[this.state.sortDirection]
                : 'asc',
    });
};

props

tableData={orderBy(
                    this.state.tableData,
                    this.state.columnToSort,
                    this.state.sortDirection
                )}
handleSort = {this.handleSort}
columnToSort = {this.state.columnToSort}
sortDirection = {this.state.sortDirection}
```

I know it may be hard to read, because I've got many components, but pasted only things I use to do a sort.
Can you tell me why when clicking on second table header `priority`, sorting works, and when clicking on other headers it don't?
If you have any better ideas for sorting, please let me know.

Comment: how is your table data looks like, have you checked the id's passed to sorting function?

Comment: Yes, I've checked id's (columnName) and it's exactly the same as `header id` `(el.id)`. My table data changes, it depends on whatyou type in a form, but it's saved in local storage.

Table data: `[{"name":"Ccc","priority":"High","status":false,"id":1519566683434},

{"name":"Aaa","priority":"High","status":false,"id":1519566688999}]`

Answer (score 3):

I'm hopping i understand your goal here, you are trying to sort the data via a click on the table's headers and toggle it to sort it in ascending or descending manner.

If this is correct i would take a simpler approach.

**Sorting by dynamic key**
You can create a `Th` component of your own that will take an `onClick` prop and an `id` prop where the `id` is the name of the object's key.

When the `Th` is clicked it will invoke the handler and will pass the `id` (the object's key) to the handler.
This way you can sort on the `key` that got passed by the child.

**Ascending Or Descending**
We only have 2 options for sorting - Ascending or Descending. This means we can use a Boolean instead of a string (that will simplify our logic a bit).
So after each click on a given `Th` we will set a new Boolean object in our `state` when the key being the `id` of the `Th` and we will flip it's value.
This way we can conditionally sort by the given key either in an ascending or descending way.

Here is a small running example:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'John', age: 32 },
  { name: 'Mike', age: 27 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 31 },
  { name: 'Criss', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Tom', age: 18 },
]

class Th extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { onClick, id } = this.props;
    onClick(id);
  }
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    return (
      <th onClick={this.handleClick}>{value}</th>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: data
  }
  handleSort = (id) => {
    this.setState(prev => {
      return {
        [id]: !prev[id],
        users: prev.users.sort((a, b) => prev[id] ? a[id] < b[id] : a[id] > b[id] )
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <Th onClick={this.handleSort} id="name" value="Name" />
            <Th onClick={this.handleSort} id="age" value="Age" />
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            users.map(user => (
              <tr>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.age}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: it's a great idea, but when I try to implement this code, infinity loop appears after `npm start`. I keep my data in `state`, so it may be the reason. Any ideas how to use this code when data is in state?

Comment: Ok, just needed to add `() =>` in `onClick`, so it looks like this now

`onClick={() => this.props.handleSort(id)}`. Somehow it still didn't work (I mean only 1 column sorts, other not, just like I wrote before), but thanks to you I finally figured out.